# Select all available fields in LINQ query when joining two DataTables

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I am writing a function that joins two DataTables using LINQ, the problem is that I do not know in advance what columns the two tables contain, apart from the columns the tables will be joined on.

```
string id = "ID";    
DataTable tableJoined = new DataTable();
tableJoined.Columns.Add(id, typeof(string));
tableJoined.Columns.Add("NAME", typeof(string));
tableJoined.Columns.Add("STOCK", typeof(string));


 var result = from dataRows1 in table1.AsEnumerable()
              join dataRows2 in table2.AsEnumerable()
              on dataRows1.Field<string>(id) equals dataRows2.Field<string>(id) 
              select tableJoined.LoadDataRow(new object[]
                                 {
                                    dataRows1.Field<string>(id),
                                    dataRows1.Field<string>(1),
                                    dataRows2.Field<string>(1)
                                  }, false);
            result.CopyToDataTable();
```

I can build the `tableJoined` DataTable and add columns on the go to accomodate the final structure of `tableJoined`, but how do I update the LINQ query to populate `tableJoined` with all available fields? Right now it only populates "ID", "NAME" and "STOCK" by knowing how many columns the tables contain. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
var tableJoined = table1.Clone(); // create columns from table1

// add columns from table2 except id
foreach (DataColumn column in table2.Columns)
{
    if (column.ColumnName != id)
        tableJoined.Columns.Add(column.ColumnName, column.DataType);
}

tableJoined.BeginLoadData();

foreach (DataRow row1 in table1.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataRow row2 in table2.Rows)
    {
        if (row1.Field<string>(id) == row2.Field<string>(id))
        {
            var list = row1.ItemArray.ToList(); // items from table1

            // add items from table2 except id
            foreach (DataColumn column in table2.Columns)
                if (column.ColumnName != id)
                    list.Add(row2[column]);

            tableJoined.Rows.Add(list.ToArray());
        }
    }
}

tableJoined.EndLoadData();
```